# How to print list of numbers in same column per its unit using println?

Tags: java, arrays

This is a dumb question I will admit it but its a teeny little part of my big computing project that I just cannot fix. To break it up, I want to print my array values on a new line.

For the aesthetic appeal, I need the units of my values to be in the same columns... So this comes up when I code:

1

2

3

10

111

0

My code:

```
public void display() {

        int j;

            System.out.println(name);
            for (j = 0; j < treesOfForest.length; j++) {
                if (treesOfForest[j] != null) {
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    System.out.printf("%d",(j+1));
                    System.out.println( " :   " + treesOfForest[j]);
                }
            }
}
```

---

My expected output:

[Expected Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YUcO.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to achieve your spacing, one option is to use `String#format`:

```
int[] treesOfForest = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 10, 111, 0};
for (int j=0; j < treesOfForest.length; j++) {
    System.out.println(String.format("%3d", treesOfForest[j]));
}

  1
  2
  3
 10
111
  0
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the size of the longest string in the array `maxLength`, Or you can assume that all strings will not be longer than a given number : 
`int maxLength = 100 // as example`

Then use it to print like this : `System.out.printf("%" + maxLength + "s%n", treesOfForest[j]);`

```
public void display() {

        int j;
        int maxLength = 100; // 
        System.out.println(name);
        for (j = 0; j < treesOfForest.length; j++) {
             if (treesOfForest[j] != null) {
                 System.out.printf("%" + maxLength + "s%n", treesOfForest[j]);
             }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `printf` as you did, however, you need to include a minimum width. In `printf`, if given "%3d" this states the minimum width for any number interpolated should be 3 columns. I.e. if its less than 3 digits it will be left-padded with spaces. You can also change this behaviour. For example, "%03d", this will left pad with 0's instead of spaces.

```java
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] treesOfForest = {10,5,7,9,111};
    int j;
    for (j = 0; j < treesOfForest.length; j++) {
        System.out.printf("%3d : %3d\n", (j+1), treesOfForest[j]);
    }
  }
}
```

[Test Code](https://repl.it/@femioladipo/UnderstatedAmusingExtraction)

TL;DR use `System.out.printf("%<min-width>d", numberToPrint);` ensuring min-width is greater or equal to the most digits in any of your numbers.

For more information about `printf` [visit](https://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet).

Answer (score 0):

you can use string to solve this issue

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            printList();
    }

    public static void printList() {
        int maxLen = 0;
        int arr[]={1, 2, 3, 10, 111, 0};
        for (int i=0 ; i<arr.length; i++) {
            int len = String.valueOf(arr[i]).length();
            if (maxLen < len) {
                maxLen = len;       
            }   
        }

        for (int i=0 ; i<arr.length; i++) {
            int len = String.valueOf(arr[i]).length();
            int offset = maxLen - len;
            String spaces = "";

            for (int j=0; j<offset; j++) {
                spaces += " ";
            }
            System.out.println(spaces + arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```